# Swing text field visibility issue

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I am trying to make a frame and add a text field inside it.
For that I used `JTextField`. But it's not appearing.

### Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Tst
{
    JFrame f;
    JTextField tf;

    public Tst()
    {
        f=new JFrame();
        tf=new JTextField(10);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.add(tf);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Tst();
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget about the null-layout, use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead. But if it's a requirement, you also have to set the location and size for the textfield. (you could use `setBounds(x, y, width, height`)

Comment: Thanks, setBounds() worked.But i have seen codes in which textfield is getting added without using setBounds().That's why i was not using setBounds().

Comment: Yes, with a proper layout manager there is no need to call `setBounds()`, but I think with a null-layout it is (or  `setLocation()` & `setSize()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use a layout manager, you need to set its bounds using `JTextField`'s `setBounds(x, y, width, height)` method, where `x` and `y` are position of the textfield in the `JFrame`:

```
tf.setBounds(100 , 100 , 100 , 20 );
```

First set layout to your frame, then add elements and components to it, like in the full code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Tst
{
    public Tst()
    {
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
        tf.setBounds(100 , 100 , 100 , 20 );

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(tf);

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Tst();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've been said use a proper [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for example [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html):

Don't use null layout, see [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) and [Null layout is Evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Tst {
    JFrame f;
    JTextField tf;

    public Tst() {
        f=new JFrame();
        tf=new JTextField(10);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Add a proper layout BEFORE adding elements to it. (Even if you need it to be null (Which I don't recommend) you need to write it here).
        f.add(tf);
        f.pack(); //Use pack(); so Swing can render the size of your window to it's preferred size 
        //f.setSize(400, 400); //If you really need to set a window size, do it here
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Don't forget this line.
    }
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        new Tst();
    }
}
```